# Creating a dictionary with values a list of items

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am working on program to create a dictionary of list of items values
here is code

```
list_4 = ['A&A OMSS 10.1.2.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 Authorisation_Response', 'A&A OMSS 10.1.2.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 Authentication_Response', 'OMSS A&A 10.1.1.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Authorsiation_Request', 'OMSS A&A 10.1.1.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Authentication_Request', 'A&A AFM 10.1.2.0/24 10.1.3.0/24 Authorisation_Response', 'AFM A&A 10.1.3.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Priviliged_Authentication_Request', 'A&A AFM 10.1.2.0/24 10.1.3.0/24 Privilged_Authentication_Response', 'AFM A&A 10.1.3.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Priviliged_Authorisation_Request', 'A&A AFM 10.1.2.0/24 10.1.3.0/24 Authorisation_Response']
dict_1 = {'OMSS': '10.1.1.0/24', 'A&A': '10.1.2.0/24', 'AFM': '10.1.3.0/24', 'ATM': '10.1.4.0/24'}

for key, value in dict_1.items():
    for i in list_4:
        src_sys, dst_sys, src, dst, fun = i.split()
        if src_sys.strip() == key.strip():
            dict_2[key] = (src+" "+dst+" "+fun)
```

i am getting the below output

```
{'A&A': '10.1.2.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 Authorisation_Response', 'AFM': '10.1.3.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Priviliged_Authorisation_Request', 'OMSS': '10.1.1.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Authorsiation_Request'}
```

but i want the below output

```
{'A&A': [list of flows that start with A&A], 'AFM': [list of flows that start with AFM]', 'OMSS': [list of flows that start with OMSS]}
```

Comment: i am getting the below output
{'A&A': '10.1.2.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 Authorisation_Response',
 'AFM': '10.1.3.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Priviliged_Authorisation_Request',
 'OMSS': '10.1.1.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Authorsiation_Request'}

but i want the below output

{'A&A': [list of flows that start with A&A],
 'AFM': [list of flows that start with AFM]',
 'OMSS': [list of flows that start with OMSS]}

Comment: Use defaultdict to append items to a list of values for each key. check my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are overwriting the value for the specific key iteratively instead of appending them to a list as you require.

`collections.defaultdict` is made specifically for this purpose. Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Check this code -

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_2 = defaultdict(list)  #dictionary where each value is an empty list by default

for key, value in dict_1.items():
    for i in list_4:
        src_sys, dst_sys, src, dst, fun = i.split()
        if src_sys.strip() == key.strip():
            dict_2[key].append(src+" "+dst+" "+fun) #<---- append to the key's value
            
dict_2 = dict(dict_2)
```

```
{'OMSS': ['10.1.1.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Authorsiation_Request',
          '10.1.1.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Authentication_Request'],
 'A&A': ['10.1.2.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 Authorisation_Response',
         '10.1.2.0/24 10.1.1.0/24 Authentication_Response',
         '10.1.2.0/24 10.1.3.0/24 Authorisation_Response',
         '10.1.2.0/24 10.1.3.0/24 Privilged_Authentication_Response',
         '10.1.2.0/24 10.1.3.0/24 Authorisation_Response'],
 'AFM': ['10.1.3.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Priviliged_Authentication_Request',
         '10.1.3.0/24 10.1.2.0/24 Priviliged_Authorisation_Request']}
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay, much appreciated

Comment: glad to help anytime.